# How can I use GetProcAddress() to load functions with unlimited function arguments?

Tags: arguments, argument-passing, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

I had browsed internet, but hadn't found an answer.

Previously we used static linking using def file.
Currently this approach is not suitable, because there are cases when dll is not accessible.

So now we need to load dynamically function with unlimited function arguments.

Is there a common approach? Just push in right direction or some topic related for that is OK.

Answer (score 1):

`GetProcAddress` does not care about the number of arguments the function has. If you use C++ and your problem is name mangling, you can either mark the functions with `extern "C"` or pass the mangled name to `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Yeah, but to call function I need to specify it type, should'n I? For example:  `typedef int (WINAPI *PFN_MyFunction)(char *);  PFN_MyFunction pfnMyFunction;  pfnMyFunction=(PFN_MyFunction)::GetProcAddress(hMyDll,”MyFunction”);`

Comment: Yes but you need to know that also to know how many arguments to send.

Comment: Thats why I'm here :)

Comment: How would you even know what arguments to send? Where would you get them?